# Is it safe to use $wp->query_string and $wp->request in this way?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

Is it safe to use $wp->query_string and $wp->request in this way? I escaped characters with esc_url() but I do not know if it will suffice or there may be a bug.

```
$current_url = esc_url( add_query_arg( $wp->query_string, '', home_url( $wp->request ) ) );
echo $current_url;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ensure that you call the esc_url() function as late as possible in your code to help prevent vulnerability to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks

Comment: I do not understand what you mean when you say "call the esc_url function as late as possible" You mean this: $current_url =  add_query_arg( esc_url($wp->query_string), '', home_url( esc_url($wp->request) ) ) ;
? Could you give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: Don't set the variable at the top of your php file and then use it in a link.  Escape the url when you output it to the link or wherever you are using it eg <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url()); ?>">Link</a>

Comment: @AndrewSchultz, out of interest of learning, if I'm returning a value from a function e.g. `return $url`, shouldn't I be escaping it before it's called e.g. `return esc_url( $url );`?

Comment: @AndrewSchultz, also, why wouldn't you escape it when setting the variable?

Comment: @Motivated best practice is to escape output at the latest possible time.  I'd escape it when rendering the URL in the hyperlink.